# The version ('80000') of the host compiler ('Apple clang') is not supported

Tags: xcode, cuda

I am installing CUDA 8.0.47 and i have installed Xcode 8 in my Macbook Pro OSX 10.11.6 . But it is giving me error while running the sample code of CUDA

```
 The version ('80000') of the host compiler ('Apple clang') is not supported
```

What is searched on google its saying to downgrade the version of Xcode to 7.2 or 7.3. Is there any other solution anyone found other than downgrading the Xcode version.

Answer (score 3):

You can install both versions of Xcode:

- Rename /Applications/Xcode.app to /Applications/Xcode_v8.app
- Download and install Xcode 7.x
- Rename /Applications/Xcode.app to /Applications/Xcode_7_x.app
- Rename /Applications/Xcode_v8.app to /Applications/Xcode.app

And choose one of them whenever you need it. In console:

Use Xcode 8 Command Line Tools:

`sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Use Xcode 7 Command Line Tools:

`sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode_7_x.app/Contents/Developer`

Answer (score 2):

No. You *must* use a supported host compiler version. Xcode 8 is not supported in CUDA 8. You have two choices -- use Xcode 7.x, or wait until a CUDA version which supports Xcode 8 is released.